# Python's Tkinter after() function jumps CPU

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm building a Python GUI app using tkinter.
Basically I'm starting and integrating with a different thread, while communication goes using input and output queues.

In the GUI side (the main thread where tkinter's mainloop() goes) I want to add a function which will be called on every iteration of the mainloop (I'm processing and displaying information on real-time).

So my function does something like that:

```
def loop(self):
    try:
        output_type, data = wlbt.output_q.get_nowait()
        pass  # if got something out of the queue, display it!
    except Queue.Empty:
        pass
    self.loop_id = self.after(1, self.loop)
```

While when starting the program I just call `self.loop_id = self.after(1, self.loop)`.

So two things that bother me:

1. The loop function raise the CPU usage by 30%-50%. If I disable it then it's good.
2. I want to be able to use `after_idle()` to maximize the refresh-rate, but I wasn't able to just replace it - got and error.

I'm sensing there's something I don't fully understand. What can be done to address these issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `self.after(1, self.loop)` you are asking for a function to be run roughly once per millisecond. It's not at all surprising that the CPU usage goes up since you are making 1000 function calls per second.

Given that humans cannot perceive that many changes, if all you're doing is updating the display then there's no reason to do that more than 20-30 times per second.

Comment: Got it, and if I want it to get executed whenever the mainloop has resources to do it, what should I do? Should I do it with `after_idle()`? If so, how?

Comment: @galah92: my advice is just what I wrote: call your function every 20 or 30 seconds. If your goal is to update a display for humans, doing a check any more often than that is just wasting compute cycles.